# Reload subview with animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, subview

I want to reload a scroll view on click of a button.I also need to create animation similar to pushing a new view while reloading the scroll view with new values. Any ideas ?

**Updated :**

I have a main class in which i call another viewcontroller :

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  controller = [[abc alloc]initWithNibName:@"abc" bundle:nil];

  [self displayContentController:controller];

  }
- (void) displayContentController: (UIViewController*) content;{
  [self addChildViewController:content];                      
  content.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,20, 320, 1048);
  [self.view addSubview:content.view];

  [content didMoveToParentViewController:self];
  }

A button is added to this child view. I want to create a new object of child view and reload that view to the main view on button click. Is it possible !

Comment: First, there is not reload on scroll view, second, you sir need to give us something (code), for us to be able to help you..

Comment: Agreed: You need to do some more research so that you can adequately describe what you're trying to do. I assume you meant to reload the data in a *table view* (that happens to be embedded in a scroll view), but I have no idea what you mean regarding the animation. Take the time to rework your question in a way that allows others to answer you versus its current state, which requires a crystal ball and a demonic familiar to divine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reload the data from a *table view* then you can do this with the method `(void)reloadSections:(NSIndexSet *)sections withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation`  with this you can do a reload with an animation. For the animations possible look in the [Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadSections:withRowAnimation:).

If that does not help you, you need to rework your question.